# Storing Individual UISwitch States in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

I have a `UITableView` that has Two ProtoType Cells both with separate `TableViewCell` subclassess. In one of the prototype cells I have multiple switches. The user can select the item they want in the table and turn the switch on that corresponds to the item. I would like to be able to store the `UISwitch`state so if the user navigates away and comes back they will see what they have selected previously.

I'm trying to store the `UISwitch`state in a dictionary and then call the state back when the table gets reloaded.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
 @IBAction func switchState(sender: AnyObject) {

    if mySwitch.on{

        savedItems = NSMutableDictionary(object: mySwitch.on, forKey: "switchKey")

        standardDefaults.setObject("On", forKey: "switchKey")

    }
    else{



        standardDefaults.setObject("Off", forKey: "switchKey")
```

and then this is in the `awakeNib` section:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.mySwitch.on =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchKey")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["switchKey" : true])

}
```

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is:

Having a dictionary (or any other data type) that is from the exact same size as your data source.

And in your

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

you need to that dictionary for the row `indexPath.row` and then mainpulate your cell

Note, your dictionary should be static

Comment: So just to clarify I should call the 'override func tableView' inside the prototype cell subclass and modify the cell within there. Correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: No what William means is that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function you need to check the state of the dictionary for the switch you're trying to set, and then set it to what's stored in the dictionary.

Comment: @Rico exactly as pbush said

Comment: Got it thanks guys. I will give it a shot and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: @pbush25 I'm trying to check the value in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function. I'm calling `for saved in cell.savedItems {  }`  Should I be checking in a for loop to extract the state. After I get the information then pass it to `NSUserDefaults`. It seems like there should be an easier way. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rico I added a new answer that will hopefully provide more insight.

Answer (score 1):

Putting my answer here instead of a comment so I can hopefully explain things better. You need to have some sort of system to keep up with which dictionary item corresponds with which `UISwitch`. Your best bet would probably be to have a dictionary `var uiDictionary = [String : Bool]()` where your keys are a string that you know corresponds to a specific switch. Then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would try to access each dictionary item, check if it's the one for the switch you're trying to set, and then set it. Don't know your exact setup, but it would look something like this...

```
func cellForRowAtIndexPath() {
    //other stuff here
    //now set your switches

    for (key, value) in uiDictionary {
        switch(key) {
            case "Switch1":
                 if value == true {
                     cell?.switch1.setOn(true, animated: true)
                 } else {
                     cell?.switch1.setOn(false, animated: true)
                 }
            break
            case "Switch2":
                 if value == true {
                     cell?.switch1.setOn(true, animated: true)
                 }  else {
                     cell?.switch1.setOn(false, animated: true)
                 }
        }

     }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, this makes good sense. Thanks for the explanation I will give it a go and let you know.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is possible because I created a `NSDictionary` that stores the `bool` state. I know it has information in it because I have printed it out and it has what it needs. But the problem is I have four rows and four switches. When I store the row value it always comes back as row 4. So when the reload happens everything is turned on because every row references to 4. I'm not sure how to separate the row references number. So I get 1 when I switch row one, and 2 when I switch row two, etc. What do you think?

Comment: Are you using the code that I gave above? What I wrote will iterate through each entry in the dictionary and set the appropriate switch for that specific cell, and will work for multiple cells.

Comment: Right that is what I thought but when I print the dictionary from the loop I get the same values every time. Meaning I'll get `switchKey = true` for every row. I found this out because I was trying to figure out the problem and so I put a check in the loop and found the dictionary was taking in one value for everything. Also I put in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` `if indexPath.row == 1 {flip the switch}` Just to ensure I was getting the right values. But What I found from that test is when I select row one it turns on row fours switch. So this tells me its storing four only. Any thoughts?